# How to change the length of the margins of a CV

Tags: margins, cv

I'm working on this CV using the [Fortyseconds template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/forty-seconds-cv/pztcktmyngsk). I really like the template but I find that the right margin is too small. I would like to change it at more than 0.002 but following how the code is written if I change the value, it changes also the left margin that in my opinion has no problem. So, there is a way in which I have the left margin at 0.002 and the right margin at 0.004?

```
%set page margins
\newlength\sidebarwidth%
\newlength\topbottommargin%
\newlength\leftrightmargin%
\newlength\sidebartextwidth
% default values
\setlength{\sidebarwidth}{0.34\paperwidth}
\setlength{\topbottommargin}{0.02\paperheight}
\setlength{\leftrightmargin}{0.02\paperwidth}
% user overwrites
\DeclareOptionX{sidebarwidth}{\setlength{\sidebarwidth}{#1}}
\DeclareOptionX{topbottommargin}{\setlength{\topbottommargin}{#1}}
\DeclareOptionX{leftrightmargin}{\setlength{\leftrightmargin}{#1}}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: I haven't seen the full code, but instead of using setlenght{\leftrightmargin........} creat two separate ones eg \setlength{left margin.... } and one for the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add after `\documentclass[ ....`

```
\geometry{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    top=\topbottommargin,
    bottom=\topbottommargin,
    left=\sidebarwidth + \leftrightmargin,
    right=0.04\paperwidth, % set the right margin <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
```

[image: a]

Your code should now start as

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[
    a4paper,
     showframes, % ONLY to show the margins <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
]{fortysecondscv}


\geometry{
    top=\topbottommargin,
    bottom=\topbottommargin,
    left=\sidebarwidth + \leftrightmargin,
    right=0.04\paperwidth, % set the right margin <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}

......
```

The side (left) width can be changed from the class options, for example:

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    showframes, % ONLY to show the margins <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    sidebarwidth=0.4\paperwidth,
]{fortysecondscv}
```